# OpenSSL 1.0.1e failed in FIPS mode

Tags: linux, openssl, suse, fips

I am compiling OpenSSL with FIPS.

When I tried running openssl binary in FIPS mode by exporting OPENSSL_FIPS=1, it is giving below error,

```
47657709811344:error:2D06B06F:FIPS routines:FIPS_check_incore_fingerprint:fingerprint does not match:fips.c:232:
```

My platform is Linux Suse.

Please help.

EDIT 1:

I am using below command to build

```
./Configure no-idea fips --prefix=build/Linux.2.6.16_x86-64_gcc-4.1.2/result  --with-fipslibdir=Current/lib/Linux.2.6.16_x86-64_gcc-4.1.2/ --with-fipsdir=Current linux-x86_64 --openssldir=/opt/VRTSssl shared no-zlib no-sse2 no-ec2m

make depend ; make ; make install
```

Comment: How are you compiling? Are you using static linking to OpenSSL, or dynamic linking? If static, how *exactly* are you invoking GCC and/or make?

Comment: This is probably a dumb question, but did you build and install `openssl-fips-2.0.N`? `--with-fipslibdir` and friends should point to the `openssl-fips-2.0.N` installation.

Comment: Been years since this question was asked. But for future reference, follow these steps EXACTLY: https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-2.0.pdf minimize the number of options (even if the doc says they will work) and don't make assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

> make depend ; make ; make install

Do a `make all` rather than just `make`. One of the issues here is `make install` builds things rather than just installing things. Its broken other platforms in the past, such as Android. One way I know to avoid the building of things during install is to issue the `make all`.

Another bad thing about the OpenSSL script that embeds the fingerprint is that it fails silently. I learned that the hard way on Android too.

---

> --with-fipsdir=Current linux-x86_64

This space is probably causing problems.

---

> --with-fipsdir=...

I seem to recall the fips directory *should* include `fips-2.0` somewhere. Its a little different than just `openssldir`.

---

> --with-fipslibdir=Current/lib/Linux.2.6.16_x86-64_gcc-4.1.2/

Since you are using `--with-fipsdir`, I don't believe you need `--with-fipslibdir`.

---

Does the openssl binary have an `libcrypto.so` dependency or `rpath` set? I'm on a Mac now so I can't check what Linux does.

Comment: I tried doing make all but it is failing with same error. I dont understand "This space is probably causing problems." comment. yes it is depending on libcrypto.

Comment: Yes, _RPATH_ setting is done by the _openssl_ executable build. Also `--with-fipsdir` is equivalent to setting _FIPSDIR_ var for `Configure`. Default _openssl-fips_ install dir is: _/usr/local/ssl/fips-2.0_.