# Apache 2.4.18 with 1.02f fips2.0 fingerprint error

Tags: apache, openssl, fips

Can someone please help me I have recently upgraded my apache from 2.4.12 to 2.4.18 and I have also updated the openssl 1.01e to 1.02f.

I followed the steps from here https://blog.ivanristic.com/2013/08/compiling-apache-with-static-openssl.html

I ran this command

```
./configure \
    --prefix=/opt/httpd \
    --with-included-apr \
    --enable-ssl \
    --with-ssl=/opt/openssl-1.0.2f \
    --enable-ssl-staticlib-deps \
    --enable-mods-static=ssl

[Sat Mar 12 01:29:20.451074 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 30351:tid 139841902528256] SSL Library Error: error:2D06B06F:FIPS routines:FIPS_check_incore_fingerprint:fingerprint does not match
[Sat Mar 12 01:29:20.451083 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 30351:tid 139841902528256] AH02312: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting.
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

Can anyone please help with this issue. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenSSL 1.0.1e failed in FIPS mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701194/openssl-1-0-1e-failed-in-fips-mode)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).